# Creating a multi-level menu that only shows child pages when on parent page

Tags: css, wordpress, menu, wordpress-theming

Iv created a sidebar menu in Wordpress which has 2 levels to it.

I dont want to display the child pages on the second level of the menu, until the parent page has been clicked.

I do not want it to happen on click like an accordion, but just to display once the parent page has loaded.

How can i do this without creating other menus?

I want to create a similar method to this sites sidebar: http://www.md-solicitors.co.uk/for-individuals/employment-hr/

Thanks

Comment: You could try adding a class to `<body>` with the page category. So then, you can set your CSS to only show those nav items when they are a child of that class.

Comment: You will need to use Javascript to accomplish this. There are some similar Javascript questions with code answers. If you have a search for this then you can see examples, some might be using the hover() function but you can easily change it to be click() for the submenu options.